# A question on the definite article

Tags: definite-articles

**The implications** for children growing up in poverty-stricken or traumatic environments were significant.

has intensified in Sweden in the wake of Russia’s annexation of Crimea in 2014 and **recent** incursions into Swedish airspace and territorial waters by Russian planes and submarines.

Pro-Europeans will argue that the report shows that **opponents** of EU membership have yet to outline a credible alternative.

I would like to know why the first example has "THE" but the other two not. What is the difference?

How about this?

**Implications** for children growing up in poverty-stricken or traumatic environments were significant.

has intensified in Sweden in the wake of Russia’s annexation of Crimea in 2014 and **the recent** incursions into Swedish airspace and territorial waters by Russian planes and submarines.

Pro-Europeans will argue that the report shows that **the opponents** of EU membership have yet to outline a credible alternative.

Comment: There are a number of related posts here as well as on [ell.se] -- please check. Good Luck.

Comment: The first two examples are correct. The third might sound a bit more idiomatic if you get rid of one of the "thats"; e.g., "Pro-Europeans will argue the report shows that opponents of EU membership have yet to outline a credible alternative." While "...that the report ... that the opponents" is not incorrect, it sounds somewhat awkward.

Comment: Hi Mark, to which examples were you referring to? Above"How about this?" or under?

Answer (score 1):

In the first sentence, we are not talking about any random implications - which implications? **the** implications, meaning, a specific thing that is probably in the next or prior sentence.

In the second sentence, recent is an adjective. So we’d ask this question: what type of incursions were they? **recent incursions**

In the third sentence, we are not talking about specific opponents (I.e. Bob and Joe) rather, just any opponents that exist.

Comment: Does it mean that I can say The recent implications for children growing up in poverty-stricken or traumatic environments were significant.

Comment: Yes - it is still the implications, they are just recent now. The word recent is just an adjective on the definite phrase. @whowhenhow

Comment: But why I can't say the recent incursions? which incursions? the recent incursions.

Comment: I was referring to the second sentence where there is no "the".

Comment: Because the incursions still aren’t definite - they’re just some random incursions! the word recent has nothing to do with it.

Comment: How would you make it more definite? I mean, it is about recent incursions, not some abstract or potential incursions. These incursions happened and we know when and where and by who.

Comment: ..Add a the :).

Comment: I am really confused :{

Comment: "Recent incursions" informs you that some occurred, whereas "the recent incursions" assumes that you already heard about them.

Answer (score 1):

In all three of these sentences, you could either put *the* in or leave it out, and the meaning would be almost exactly the same.

So you're trying to make sense of what is more or less random data, and not succeeding, which isn't surprising.